# My codes do not work for sections in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to set sections in a TableView. Each section has different value types, please see my codes. But it doesn't work. Please advise correct way to set up values in sections. Please refer to screenshot for error message.   Note: I deleted ")" at the end of var detailsInSection because it won't show correctly.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo5tt.png)

```
var sectionTitles = ["WebSite", "Date Saved", "Document Used","Add Notes"]

var detailsInSection = [([String], [NSDate],[AnyObject],[String])]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return detailsInSection[section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailsCell")

    cell?.textLabel!.text = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Hi return true, thanks and please also add half ")" at the end of var detailsInSection.

Comment: Mike, do it yourself by using the [edit] button. :) Thanks.

Comment: Done. I thought I don't have the authority.

Comment: You always do *on your own posts*. In other situations, it's indeed related to your reputation score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var detailsInSection = [([String], [NSDate],[AnyObject],[String])]
```

The above is an array of tuple. I'm guessing from the rest of your code that you want an array of arrays.

```
var detailsInSection = [[String](), [NSDate](), [AnyObject](), [String]()]
```

Your array would have 4 elements, each of which is an array.

If you want to handle the different types then use a switch statement.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailsCell")!
    switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
cell.textLabel!.text = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        case 1:
             let date = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
             // Do some date formatting etc
             cell.textLabel!.text = PUT YOUR FORMATTED DATE HERE
        case 2:
             // Do any type casting etc.
             let object = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] 
             // Convert object to whatever is needed in text format.
             cell.textLabel!.text = PUT YOUR OUTPUT HERE
        case 3:
             // This is a string so just assign it.
             cell.textLabel!.text = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        default:
             // What to do here? Should never happen.
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing tuples consisting of (String, NSDate, AnyObject, String), store an array for each section. This will provide you more flexibility and easier access. Change your code to this:

```
var detailsInSection = [[AnyObject]]() // Note the type is 'AnyObject', so you can still store your strings, dates etc. here

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return detailsInSection[indexPath.section].count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DetailsCell")!
    cell.textLabel!.text = detailsInSection[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].description // Description will transfer your object to a string. If you want to change this behavior, you must process your objects according to their type.
    return cell
}
```